# python : define a method equals to another

Tags: python

I would like to define a method equals to another one in python. My need is to factorize code as methods' name is retrieve by other mean (here, config files I want to analyze) and for some of them, job to be done is the same.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
class Apache:

  def __init__(self):
    self.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf = self.wsgi_conf
    self.keystone_wsgi_main_conf  = self.wsgi_conf

  def wsgi_conf(self):
    return {
        ...
    }

  # this works but implies loads of code duplication
  #def keystone_wsgi_admin_conf(self):
  #   return {
  #      ...
  #   }
```

This is not working, printing methods list of an instance of this class does not show `keystone_wsgi_main_conf` nor `keystone_wsgi_admin_conf`.

I would have think this would work directly, obviously this does not.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you explain the desired behaviour a bit more? If you want `keystone_wsgi_admin_conf ` to be a method of the instance, you need to say `setattr(self,"keystone_wsgi_admin_conf",self.wsgi_conf)` in `__init__`.

Comment: You're doing nothing wrong.

Comment: @Ardweaden It will have the same effect as if he'd assign it the way as in the question.

Comment: "printing methods list of an instance of this class does not show ..." — I think it *does* show them. At least they appear in `dir(myinstance)`. Please demonstrate what you mean.

Comment: Your question is actually pretty interesting. I've given an answer that hopefully explains the internals rather than rehashing the excellent answer already there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, there are two ways:

You could call one method from the other (or a third one from both):

```
class Apache:

    def _wsgi_conf(self):
        return {
            ...
        }

    def keystone_wsgi_admin_conf(self):
        return self._wsgi_conf()
    def keystone_wsgi_main_conf(self):
        return self._wsgi_conf()
```

Or you just define the methods the same. This is the same approach you intended to use, but on class level.

```
class Apache:

    def _wsgi_conf(self):
        return {
            ...
        }

    keystone_wsgi_admin_conf = _wsgi_conf
    keystone_wsgi_main_conf = _wsgi_conf
```

Comment: The second option won't *exactly* work because `Apache.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf.__name__` will be `'_wsgi_conf'`. You could create new function object referencing the same code object, but why? The first part is the right answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Setting the attribute `keystone_wsgi_admin_conf` on an instance of a class like `self` is perfectly fine. As you noticed, the "method" won't show up as a method. Here's why:

Methods in a class object are regular functions. Functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), specifically, non-data descriptors, because they don't have a `__set__` method.

When you invoke [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) through the dot operator, it will not find an attribute like `wsgi_conf` in your instance. Instead, it will find a non-data descriptor in your class, bind it to assign `self`, and invoke it. The result is something like:

```
>>> x = Apache()
>>> x.wsgi_conf()
```

is internally

```
>>> type(x).__dict__['wsgi_conf'].__get__(x)()
```

Now the invocation of an attribute like `keystone_wsgi_admin_conf`, defined on an instance, will be just

```
 >>> x.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf()
```

That's because you already did the binding already happened in `__init__`.

```
self.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf = self.wsgi_conf
```

is equivalent to

```
self.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf = type(self).__dict__['wsgi_conf'].__get__(self)
```

A bound method that is assigned this way will override any class non-data descriptor with the same name. It will not override magic methods, however, and it will not override data descriptors, like [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). The details are in the [HowTo in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors).

The reason that methods assigned like that don't show up in your method list is that the method list is generated from the class, not the instance.

While the method you are using works fine, and may offer a level of flexibility in some situations, it is likely not optimal in your case. If you have the same assignment in every single instance, and are trying to avoid code duplication, you are probably just wasting references. The way to avoid code duplication is to write functions/method and then *call* them, instead of copy and pasting.

**TL;DR**

Your assignment will work just as expected, but you should do the following instead:

```
class Apache:

    def __init__(self):
        self.keystone_wsgi_admin_conf = self.wsgi_conf
        self.keystone_wsgi_main_conf  = self.wsgi_conf

    def wsgi_conf(self):
        return {
             ...
        }

   def keystone_wsgi_admin_conf(self):
        return self.wsgi_conf()

   def keystone_wsgi_main_conf(self):
        return self.wsgi_conf()
```